# Decode JWT and create authenticated User in Laravel microservice, merging with local user data

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, microservices

**Background**

I have a microservice setup the flow is:

```
client > api gateway > auth server > api gateway > microservice
```

1. The client has a 'external' JWT from Laravel passport
2. Client sends request to the api gateway with the 'external' JWT
3. The api gateway sends a request to the auth server (Laravel passport) with the 'external' JWT
4. The auth server verifies the user is still active and returns a new 'internal' JWT to the api gateway containing the users profile, groups etc
5. The api gateway forwards the request with this new 'internal' JWT to the microservice
6. **(all fine up to this point)**
7. The Microservice verifies the 'internal' JWT using the auth servers public key
8. The microservice decodes the 'internal' JWT and creates a user object from the profile contained within
9. If the microservice has a local users table (e.g. for microservice specific user data), merge the local data with the JWT data

---

**Microservice Authentication**

I have created a JwtGuard that can decode the JWT and create a user using GenericUser:

auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
],
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::extend('jwt', function ($app) {
            return new JwtGuard($app['request']);
        });
    }
```

JwtGuard.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Services\Auth;

use Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser;
use Illuminate\Auth\GuardHelpers;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class JwtGuard implements Guard {

    use GuardHelpers;

    /**
     * @var Request
     */
    private $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * Get the currently authenticated user.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function user()
    {
        if (!is_null($this->user)) {
            return $this->user;
        }

        if(!$jwt = $this->getJwt()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->decode($jwt);
    }

    /**
     * Validate a user's credentials.
     *
     * @param  array $credentials
     * @return bool
     */
    public function validate(array $credentials = [])
    {
        if(!$jwt = $this->getJwt()) {
            return false;
        }

        return !is_null($this->decode($jwt))?true:false;
    }

    /**
     * Decode JWT and return user
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    private function decode($jwt)
    {
        $publicKey = file_get_contents(storage_path('oauth-public.key'));

        try {
            $res = JWT::decode($jwt, $publicKey, array('RS256'));
            return $this->user = new GenericUser(json_decode(json_encode($res->user), true));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private function hasAuthHeader()
    {
        return $this->request->header('Authorization')?true:false;
    }

    private function getJwt()
    {
        if(!$this->hasAuthHeader()){
            return null;
        }

        preg_match('/Bearer\s((.*)\.(.*)\.(.*))/', $this->request->header('Authorization'), $jwt);

        return $jwt[1]?$jwt[1]:null;
    }

}
```

---

**The problem**

This works ok(ish), except that:

- I can't use authorization policies properly as GenericUser doesn't have the can() method
- There is no easy way to merge with a local user object

---

**What I have so far**

I have tried the following to merge the local user data with the JWT profile:

```
private function decode($jwt)
    {
        $publicKey = file_get_contents(storage_path('oauth-public.key'));

        try {
            $res = JWT::decode($jwt, $publicKey, array('RS256'));
            $this->user = new GenericUser(json_decode(json_encode($res->user), true));
            $this->user->localUser = \App\User::where('user_id', $this->user->id)->first();
            return $this->user;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

but this still leaves GenericUser not having the can() function.

---

**Help...please!**

I can't help feel there is a better (proper?) way to achieve this using 'User' instead of 'GenericUser' which will allow all the Authentication/Authorization features in Laravel to work properly, and to merge the data easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***I solved it by adding $jwt_user to User construct to skip 'fillable':***

auth.php

```
'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'api',
],
'guards' => [
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
    ],
],
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
use App\User;
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::viaRequest('jwt', function ($request) {
            $publicKey = file_get_contents(storage_path('oauth-public.key'));

            if(!$hasAuthHeader = $request->header('Authorization')?true:false){
                return null;
            }

            preg_match('/Bearer\s((.*)\.(.*)\.(.*))/', $request->header('Authorization'), $jwt);

            try {
                $res                        = JWT::decode($jwt[1], $publicKey, array('RS256'));
                $jwt_user                   = json_decode(json_encode($res->user), true);
                $local_user                 = User::find($jwt_user['id']);
                $jwt_user['local_profile']  = $local_user?$local_user:[];
                $user                       = new User([], $jwt_user);
                return $user;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

User.php

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array(), $jwt_user = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        foreach($jwt_user as $k=>$v){
            $this->$k = $v;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to achieve this is:

```
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Laravel\Passport\Token;

$jwt = 'eyJ0...';
$publicKey = file_get_contents(storage_path('oauth-public.key'));
$res = JWT::decode($jwtToken, $publicKey, ['RS256']);
$user = Token::findOrFail($res->jti)->user;
```